# pub/sub technique to "guarantee" messages are delivered to all subscribers

Tags: c#, android, rabbitmq, message-queue

i am developing an android application and i want to broadcast some message to all my clients with RabbitMQ. is there any way wiht RabbitMQ, that supports offline clients - by offline clients I mean that if i have server submitting messages to the clients,and some clients are unreachable,the client will receive messages after it gets connected again.

Is there some open source solution for that? It seems that rabbitMQ does not do this,i might be wrong tho.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a unique queue for each client. Bind those queues to a common exchange. Then every time your client will come online it will create a connection to rabbit (earlier defined queue) and will consume messages.

I think you would better benefit from topic exchange (https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html)

And bind them to a common exchange with desired routing keys.